# ios reachability - app starts disconnected - no notification when connection established

Tags: ios, startup, reachability

My application is using the Apple Reachability class. I currently have the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

_internetReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[_internetReachability startNotifier];
```

called from `AppDelegate:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

The reachability notification works fine. I test it switching airplane mode on and off.

However, if I start the application when airplane mode is enabled, so no connectivity at startup, there is no notification when the connection is restored (airplane mode is switched off).

Any ideas why this would be? How can this program receive notifications when the connection is restored?

the reachabilityChanged method merely checks if the system is now online, and sends a new notification

```
Reachability* curReach = [note object];

NetworkStatus internetStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];

BOOL offline = internetStatus == NotReachable;

NSLog(@"%@ offline = %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), offline ? @"YES" : @"NO");

//only provide notifications if back on-line,
//offline handled after a failed api request
if (!offline)
{
    _offline = NO;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationReachabilityStatusChanged
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:@{
                                                                 kNotificationReachabilityStatusKey : [NSNumber numberWithBool:!_offline]
                                                                 }];
}
```

Comment: can you share the code you used in reachabilityChanged function?

Comment: the reachability changed isn't being hit. All I'm doing is checking if we are reachable and if so sending my own notification. See updated post.